# Is it possible to pack vmware machine files and move to blu-ray disc?

Tags: vmware-player

I have my masters on VMware. I would like to back it up somehow. My idea was to pack it (7z, WinZip, WinRar)somehow and then record on blu-ray cd. Is it possible?
When I'm packing vmware files and then when I'm unpacking them, vmware machine won't work. Very often I even have an issue with unpacking it.
Windows says that files are corrupted.
My vmware machine files are 2 GB size. (2nd disc is in pieces)
I was also trying to record virtual machine without packing it but it was the same. I was unable to move all vmfiles from blu-ray disc to hard drive.
Please help. I don't want to store my vmware machine for eternity and also I don't wan to delete it.

(I'm talking about VMWare player and files which are used to run/host some system in virtual environment.)

Comment: VMware is a company, not a product. Which product are you talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Player, make sure you've shut down the VM and closed the Player instance. If you're using Workstation or ESX/ESXi, you should shut down the VM and export the VM.

At least in Player, you should be asked if you "moved" or "copied" the VM. It's safest to use "copied."

I've been able to export and zip VMs to USB key or CD/DVD, and reload them on another machine.

You could also use snapshots to save copies of the VM, but that won't save you in the event of your VMware machine/disk(s) dying.

Make sure whatever you're using to "pack" them is doing a verification after "packing." Watch for logs/errors from your "packing" program.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which one of VMWare's many product you're using but many of them allow for you to copy VMs using the [.OVF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Virtualization_Format) format. These are single output files encapsulating one or more whole VMs including each's definitions, startup order, IP setting etc. and this format is common across a number of competing hypervisors. I couldn't recommend it higher.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to make zip virtual machine and record it to Blu ray disc successfully. But you need to have a good packing program, for me it was Win Zip (Unfortunately it is not free). And the second condition is to have good recording software and BD-ROM recorder. I used Nero Burning Rom and LG drive. And it works!